# Twitter Bootstrap's navbar with split buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, split, navbar

Is there any (fairly easy) way to get [Twitter Bootstrap's navbar](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) filled with [split button dropdowns](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)?

I'm looking for any way to separate so called *main button* from a dropdown menu containing items that belongs to that *main button* or are somehow related to it.

I tried to add two navbar items per each one -- first containing only *main button* (with caption and icon) and second containing only dropdown (without caption and icon):

[image]

[image]

But result is not much acceptable. Mainly because:

- only one part (of two pretending one button) is hovered with mouse,
- there is a visual gutter between so called *main button* and its fake dropdown,
- Bootstrap has some small bug (I think), that causes it to not hover entire area below down arrow, when an item lacks caption and icon.

Are there any other options, possibilities or workarounds for this problem? Or am I expecting too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) page has exactly, what I've been looking for, without need to put extra code or CSS.

I'm reffering to "Icons" and "Example" buttons that are perfect split buttons dropdowns, i.e. it can be clicked as single button, and you can open dropdown next to it, without touching the main button.

However, this is done via separate elements, which means huge space between main button and dropdown arrow.

[Here is](http://bootply.com/66464) a Bootply example, that replicates this code and this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Font Awesome's example! I was able to make the gap reasonably sized by adding zero margins to Font Awesome's extra classes: `.navbar-nav>li.dropdown-split-left>a {
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-nav>li.dropdown-split-right>a {
    padding-left: 7px;
    margin-left: 0;
}`

Comment: Great! Why don't you put that as a full-featured answer? :>

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you want to split the main button from the drop down. It are separate structures already (bind by the button-group class). I don't see the small bug. About the gutter `.btn`, `.navbar .btn` and `.btn-navbar` have different css rules. For hovering the button and dropdown once add / remove a extra css class and add this on mouseenter and mouseleave, see: http://bootply.com/66352

**extra css rule for hover a .btn-danger button**:

```
.buttonhover-danger
{
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #bd362f;
  background-image: none;
  *background-color: #a9302a;
}
```

**hover all button / dropdowns with the .btn-danger class**:

```
$('.btn-danger').mouseenter(function(){$('.btn-danger').addClass('buttonhover-danger')});
$('.btn-danger').mouseleave(function(){$('.btn-danger').removeClass('buttonhover-danger')});
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution! The answer to your question ("_Why split?_") is quite obvious (at least to me). I have a media list, page mostly visited, and a bunch of media related operations (like add, convert, see stats etc.), not so often used. I want mostly use option (media list) to be accessible via direct click, while less common functions to be _hidden_ in dropdown. I don't want users to click navbar item and select "List" from drop down, each time they want to go to list (very often used operation).

Comment: Answer could be simpler: Why would you use split button dropdown? The reason is exactly the same, only I want to use it in navbar.